# How do i make the html window appear to shake?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is exactly what the title says, i want to make the window shake, if you need CSS for this, how can I "call" the CSS code like a function whenever i want.

The shake effect should last for about 3 seconds, max.

Comment: Add shake animation to body within 3 seconds. Then boom your body like a shake shake. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you make a div as large as the body.
And give it a shake animation.
Like this:

```css
#myDiv {
  /* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
  animation: shake 0.5s;

  /* When the animation is finished, start again */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

#myDiv{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div id="myDiv">myDiv</div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```